# Change the last bit of an 8-bit integer

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

I want to invert the rightmost bit of an 8-bit integer e.g; if it is `00010111`, I want to transform it to `00010110`. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "8-bit integer"? Is it a `double` vector contiaining zeros and ones? Or a single number of `uint8` type? ...?

Comment: I mean 8-bit value. e.g; for 8, it's 8-bit value is 00001000, I want to change these bits to 00001001 by replacing the last 0 bit by 1 or vice versa.

Comment: Do you have `x = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]` or `x = 14`?

Comment: I have x=14. I want to replace last bit of this pixel.

Comment: samgak's answer then?

Comment: samgak suggestion work only when we replace last 0 bit with 1. I also want to replace last 1 bit with 0. Any suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [bitxor](http://kr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html) with a value of 1 (to change the last bit):

```
newvalue = bitxor(value,1)
```

You can specify a type, e.g:

```
newvalue = bitxor(value,1,'int8')
```

Comment: Thanks samgak. but this works replaces last 0 bit with 1 but didn't work when we replace last 1 bit with 0. Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: I have a string of bits having 1 and 0 and a set of pixel values in decimals. I want to replace one bit of string with last bit of each pixel. How can I do this ?

Comment: If you want to set the first bit of x to the first bit of y then try x = bitor(bitand(bitcmp(1),x),bitand(y,1)). That seems different to your original question though.